# How to pass Bind variables in Groovy Script - Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: groovy, artifactory

I have below JFrog Artifacroty AQL and trying to pass the variables dynamically. Appriciate your inputs on how to bind variables.

```
def repoName = 'star-Temp'
def query = 'items.find({"$and":[ {"repo":{"$eq":"$repoName"}}, {"path":{"$match":"com/companyname/xxx/abc*"}} ]}).sort({"$desc":["name"]})'
```

When i pass the repoName to the above AQL it should get replaced with 'star-Temp' value, populate as below

```
def query = 'items.find({"$and":[ {"repo":{"$eq":"star-Temp"}}, {"path":{"$match":"com/companyname/xxx/abc*"}} ]}).sort({"$desc":["name"]})'
```

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

```
"items.find({\"\$and\":[ {\"repo\":{\"\$eq\":\"$repoName\"}}, {\"path\":{\"\$match\":\"com/companyname/xxx/abc*\"}} ]}).sort({\"\$desc\":[\"name\"]})"

'items.find({"$and":[ {"repo":{"$eq":"' + repoName + '"}}, {"path":{"$match":"com/companyname/xxx/abc*"}} ]}).sort({"$desc":["name"]})'
```

Notice the different quotation marks and escape characters.